# How do I push my new item without creating new mongoose item

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I want to append or push my new items that I input in the array without creating new mongoose schema..what I mean is that I will only push items without creating new `_id`...Here is my code..

For mongoose.Schema()

```
const mainSchema = new Schema({
    likes:{
        type:Number,
        max:100000
    },
    people:[{
        key:{type:String},
        name:{type:String}
    }]
},{
    timestamps:true
})
```

And for the routes that will post my items..

```
router.route('/item/1').post((req,res) => {

    const { likes, people } = req.body


    const FirstItem = Main({
        likes,
        // people
    })

    FirstItem.people.push(people)

    FirstItem.save()
        .then(likes => res.json('New User Added'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error :' + err))

})
```

As you see I didn't input `new Main({})` in my post because I don't wanna create a new `_id`..but I want to push my items in my array whenever I create another new items....This is how I write it in postman..

```
{
    "likes":0,
    "people":[
        {
            "key":"Tes22t",
            "name":"Tit213an"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now if I changed something after posting this in my POST method. like `"key":"testetsee","name":"123123123"` it will give me an error like this ...
`"Error :ValidationError: people.0._id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[ { key: 'Tes22t', name: 'Tit213an' } ]\" (type Array) at path \"_id\""`

I think my problem here is pushing the item? or the post? or do I just need to update it?

**EDITED**

I have this in my frontend to pass it to my backend because I want my each item to received whose account has registered so that it can store the username and keys..

```
axios.post('http://localhost:7171/likes/item/'+1,{ people:{name:name,key:key }})
          axios.post('http://localhost:7171/likes/item/'+2,{ people:{name:name,key:key } })
          axios.post('http://localhost:7171/likes/item/'+3,{ people:{name:name,key:key } })
          axios.post('http://localhost:7171/likes/item/'+4,{ people:{name:name,key:key } })
          axios.post('http://localhost:7171/likes/item/'+5,{ people:{name:name,key:key } })
```

And then the code you give me sir is here ...

```
router.route('/item/:id').post((req,res) => {

    const id = req.params.id
    
    console.log(id)

    if (!id) return res.status(400).json({ message: "missing id" });

    const { likes, people } = req.body;

    Main
        .updateOne(
        { _id: id },
        {
            $addToSet: { people: { $each: people } },
            $set: {
                likes,
            },
        },
        )
        .then((likes) => res.json({ message: "New User Added" }))
        .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error :" + err));

})
```

Since there is 5 items that I will post simultaneously, then It should have 5 items in my database and will update the array whenever I have new user to append it in my list of array in each item object.

What I received in my postman is this...
`"Error :CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"1\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"liker-model\""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want push an element into people array of that object, you should use updateOne() instead of save()

So the code will like

```
router.route('/item/1').post((req,res) => {

    const { likes, people } = req.body

    const model = mongoose.model('collection_name', mainSchema);

    model.updateOne({like}, {$addToSet: { people: {$each: people} }})
        .then(likes => res.json('New User Added'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error :' + err))


})
```

---

after discuss with the thread owner, i create new answer with the `/1` as item id

```
const _ = require("lodash");

router.route("/item/:id").post((req, res) => {
  const id = _.get(req, "params.id");
  if (!id) return res.status(400).json({ message: "missing id" });
  const { likes, people } = req.body;

  const model = mongoose.model("collection_name", mainSchema);

  model
    .updateOne(
      { _id: id },
      {
        $addToSet: { people: { $each: people } },
        $set: {
          likes,
        },
      },
    )
    .then((likes) => res.json({ message: "New User Added" }))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error :" + err));
});
```

Comment: `mainSchema` just your schema, and i don't see any code to init a model to talk with your database. So i create a model

Here is ref about model: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

you get {. like } from your req.body. i saw it here

`const { likes, people } = req.body`

Comment: aight lol I got confused thanks brother

Comment: Btw bro how can I create a new mongoose item if I tried to create a new link of post..Example `router.route('/item/2').post((req,res) => { ` How can I add new mongoose Item with it? cause it doesn't work for me when I tried your code when creating for new mongoose Item.

Comment: Seem you want the key of the object is `/1` or `/2` ? Please recheck i will update the answer for you

Comment: Yes,something like that... because I have `5 items` and I want on them to have arrays that will append each item so that I can make a photo likes.. but I need to create new mongoose items but your code doesn't work in multiple items in `post`..So i think you have better idea?

Comment: what I mean about this is to create new item and with insert something in the array for each item so I need to post them and update them too at the same time.

Comment: If you got them..can you give a documentation so I could briefly understand it.

Comment: You will not keep posting..WHat I mean I have `5 items or 5 _id` in my database and they can be updateOne as many times as I want. that's it.

Comment: @MYTH can you explan in this code `/item/1` . the `/1` is your id of your item or something else ?

Comment: Its an item number.. not an id.. basically the _id that I mean is the 5 items I will have..I just put some numbers at it so it can be organize for 5 items.
Let say I have `item/1` `item/2` `item/3` `item/4` `item/5` that means I have 5 items in my database and I want them to push my likes in each of their array.

Comment: but I want to avoid the creating new mongoose item for each `/number` since I only need 5..

Comment: Please sir I'm out of information i don't know where I am gonna get this information.

Comment: i just edited my answer, please check again if it correct with your expect @MYTH

Comment: It's not..yet I think the req.params.id but this what it giving me in my postman 
                                                                                                                                 
```Error :CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"3\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"liker-model\```

I will try to edit it so you can check it..

Comment: Check it out sir my edited.

Comment: @MYTH could you show me your sample database record, and the different in `/1` to `/5`
and the `item` schema

Comment: Ok sir I will do wait..

Comment: here is the link in my problem [CONTINUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71537499/creating-5-items-and-updating-the-array-in-mongodb-continue-discussion-from-my)